# dd with obs and seek makes file of unexpected size

Tags: linux, dd

I'm learning to use `dd` by experimentally playing with its arguments. I would like to create a 10-byte file. I thought the following would work:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./foo count=1 bs=1 obs=9 seek=1
```

...because of these comments from the man page:

> ```
>    obs=BYTES
>           write BYTES bytes at a time (default: 512)
>    seek=N skip N obs-sized blocks at start of output
> ```

...but it does not; it creates a 2-byte file:

```
>ls -l foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 2 Mar 28 16:05 foo
```

My workaround has been:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./foo count=1 bs=1 obs=1 seek=9
```

But for my learning, I'd like to understand why the first version does not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your command `dd if=/dev/zero of=./foo count=1 bs=1 obs=9 seek=1` creates a two-byte file rather than a 10-byte file because of poorly-defined interaction between `bs` and `obs`. (Call this a program bug if you like, but it's probably better defined as a documentation bug.) You are supposed to use *either* `bs` *or* `ibs` and `obs`.

Empirically it appears that `bs` overrides `obs`, so what gets executed is `dd if=/dev/zero of=./foo count=1 bs=1 seek=1`, which creates a two-byte file as you have seen.

If you had used `dd if=/dev/zero of=./foo count=1 ibs=1 obs=9 seek=1` you would have got a 10-byte file as expected.

As an alternative, if you want to create an empty file that doesn't take any data space on disk you can use the counter-intuitively named `truncate` command:

```
truncate --size=10 foo
```

Answer (score 7):

The [POSIX manpage](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/dd/) states:

> ibs=expr
>
> Specify the input block size, in bytes, by expr (default is 512).
>
> obs=expr
>
> Specify the output block size, in bytes, by expr (default is 512).
>
> bs=expr
>
> Set both **input and output** block sizes to expr bytes, **superseding
>   ibs= and  obs=**. If no conversion other than sync,  noerror,  and
>   notrunc is specified, each input block shall be copied to the output
>   as a single block without aggregating short blocks.

Linux's `dd` works the same way. Thus, use `ibs` instead:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./foo count=1 ibs=1 obs=9 seek=1
```

Comment: Interesting to see that the POSIX manpage defines the interaction between `bs` and `ibs`/`obs` but the Linux one on (at least) Debian and Cygwin doesn't. +1 for finding that.